# PyCharm type checking doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-3.5, typing

**EDIT**

According to @Jim Fasarakis Hilliard's answer, I understand that this is not a bug, it's expected behavior. So, I would like to add to question - can I somehow force `mypy`s `--strict-optional`-like functionality in `PyCharm`'s type checker?

---

After watching couple of videos about type checking in `Python 3.5+` and `Pycharm` I thought that this should be marked as a wrong return type:

```
from typing import Optional, List
import random

def r() -> Optional[List[int]]:
    if random.choice([0, 1]):
        return [1, 2, 3]
    return None


def f() -> List[int]:
    return r()
```

[image]

The `f()` function can return either `list` of `int`s or `None` which is specified explicitely, but `PyCharm` doesn't mark `return r()` as a wrong return.

```
def f() -> List[int]:
    return None
```

[image]

For example if the `f()` function looks like above, `PyCharm` detects that there is a wrong `return` type.

Is it a bug or should I have change some settings? I increased severity of  type checking to `error`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PyCharm's type checker is probably treating `None` the same way `mypy` is, see: [The type of None and optional types](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kinds_of_types.html#the-type-of-none-and-optional-types) (At least, it's doing so in this case.)

It's the same reason why the following function type checks both in mypy (0.580) and PyCharm (build 173.4301.16):

```
def foo(x: Optional[int]) -> int:
    return x + 2
```

I *guess* one could call it a bug? Either way, `mypy` offers the [`--strict-optional`](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_line.html#additional-command-line-flags) flag to handle these and, when used, your original error is caught:

```
error: Incompatible return value type (got "Optional[List[int]]", expected "List[int]")
```

this flag will be used by default in future releases according to mypy's docs. I'd safely assume PyCharm would follow suit at some point though I can't find any relevant information in their [documentation on Type Hints](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-product.html).

Comment: Thanks, so there is no such option in PyCharm yet? It's much more comfortable for me than mypy.

Comment: @MilanoSlesarik I understand. Unfortunately I can't seem to find documentation on PyCharm's type checker so I'm not certain about any special flags it might expose.

Comment: This issue is tracked under PyCharm's [PY-24834](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-24834)